# Measure the time a browser needs to open a url completely

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, time, browser

How can I measure the time a browser needs to open a specified url? Also closing the browser afterwards.

I tried this:

```
import time
import webbrowser
start = time.time()
webbrowser.open('http://stackoverflow.com')
end = time.time()
print (end-start)
```

Python opens the url in the default browser. But the time that is measured is just the time Python needs to execute the code, not how long it took for the browser to start and completely load the Website.

What I need would be something like this:

```
#start time measurement
#open url in browser
#wait for the url to finish loading
#if url finished loading: close browser and stop time measurement
```

Is it even possible to realize this in Python? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, it's not possible with [`webbrowser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) module because the module can only open the browser window/tab and does not provide control of the browser.

You need something like [`selenium`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

For example:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
start = time.time()
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com')
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
driver.quit()
```